# Out of memory Entity Framework 4

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am hoping some one can help as I'm at a loss.

On my machine I can run a process that retrieves quite a lot of records using Entity Framework 4 and it uses at maximum about 190 000 KB. On a client machine the same process uses about 800 000 KB.

Client machine is Windows 7.

Does anyone at all have any ideas on what I can look for as to why it's using more memory on the Client machine?

Comment: With out some code to look at, or some more information, I doubt there's much anyone can offer.  There are a lot of reasons that the client machine might be using more memory, it might just be using that much memory because the machine has sufficient memory and there's no pressure to do collection.

Comment: What exactly is the client machine doing?  Can you post some code?  It would help if we knew what you were doing with the records.

Comment: It has to be something environmental. Thanks for the thoughts - i know it wasn't much to go on.

Comment: are they connecting to the same database? If the database they are connecting to has more data and you don't filter what you download then the downloaded data will need more space.